# Rails Action Mailer ArgumentError with SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send an email to multiple recipients:

```
class SubscriberMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "email@gmail.com"
  default to: Subscriber.all.map { |sub| sub.email }

  def newsletter(subscriber)
    @subscriber = subscriber
    mail subject: "New newsletter"
  end
end
```

in NewslettersController:

```
def send(newsletter)
  @subscribers = Subscriber.all
  SubscriberMailer.newsletter(@subscribers).deliver
end
```

I am getting an error:

```
ArgumentError in NewslettersController#index
An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: 'to' option expects a comma seperated list try this in SubscriberMailer, Subscriber.all.map { |sub| "#{sub.email}, " }

Comment: This has helped: default to: Subscriber.all.collect(&:email).join(","). Thanks a lot for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't about `SMTP`

Something in your `Subscriber.all.map { |sub| sub.email }` is not working. Do you use a real, working address? If not, try with one.

And if all emails are real ones, then you may try something like

```
default to: Subscriber.all.collect(&:email).join(",")
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `default to:`:

```
class SubscriberMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "email@gmail.com"
  default to: Subscriber.pluck(:email).join(', ')

  # some code here
end
```